# Sorting entries alphabetically in the control panel by default.

Tags: control-panel, alphabetically, sorting

I was wondering if there was a quick way to sort entries in the control panel automatically by their titles without modifying core files. Did I miss anything in the documentation and settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not by any EE settings, however you could do this by injecting some javascript to click the `Title` column on page load. Install the [CP CSS & JS](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/cp_css_js) add-on and add the snippet below:

```
// Check to see if element exists first, then click
if ($('th[data-table_column="title"]').length > 0) { 
    $('th[data-table_column="title"]').click();
}
```

Comment: I was hoping ee had a default way of doing this. Maybe I should submit a feature request. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: In using this, it is better if it is called in document.ready.